# How to do Boolean operations on vtk Poly Data?

Tags: c++, vtk

I am trying to compute the difference between two [vtkPolyData](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkPolyData.html) by using the [vtkBooleanOperationPolyDataFilter](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkBooleanOperationPolyDataFilter.html) class. I read the only example provided in [VTK examples website](https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/Cxx/PolyData/BooleanOperationPolyDataFilter/) and I tried to use that.

However, my problem is a little bit different because I have .stl files. Therefore, first I have to translate .stl files to vtkPolyData. I am doing this with the function `convert_stl_to_polydata()`. Then, I use `compute_difference()` to compute the difference and write the output.

```
#include <string>
#include <vtkPolyData.h>
#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>
#include <vtkSTLReader.h>
#include <vtkUnstructuredGrid.h>
#include <vtkXMLUnstructuredGridWriter.h>
#include <vtkBooleanOperationPolyDataFilter.h>


vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData> convert_stl_to_polydata (std::string input) {
  auto stl_reader = vtkSmartPointer<vtkSTLReader>::New();
  stl_reader->SetFileName (input.c_str());
  stl_reader->Update();

  auto poly_data = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData>::New();
  poly_data->ShallowCopy(stl_reader->GetOutput());
  return poly_data;
}


void compute_difference (vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData> input1,
                         vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData> input2, std::string output) {

  auto boolean_operation = vtkSmartPointer<vtkBooleanOperationPolyDataFilter>::New();
  boolean_operation->SetInputData (0, input1);
  boolean_operation->SetInputData (1, input2);
  boolean_operation->SetOperationToDifference();
  boolean_operation->Update();

  // write the result as an Unstructured Grid
  auto unstructured_grid = vtkSmartPointer<vtkUnstructuredGrid>::New();
  unstructured_grid->ShallowCopy(boolean_operation->GetOutput());

  auto writer = vtkSmartPointer<vtkXMLUnstructuredGridWriter>::New();
  writer->SetFileName(output.c_str());
  writer->SetInputData(unstructured_grid);
  writer->SetDataModeToAscii();
  writer->Update();
  writer->Write();
}

int main () {
  std::string input1_filename {"Data/input_1.stl"};
  std::string input2_filename {"Data/input_2.stl"};
  std::string diff_filename {"Data/difference.vtu"};


  auto input1 = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData>::New();
  auto input2 = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData>::New();

  input1 = convert_stl_to_polydata(input1_filename);
  input2 = convert_stl_to_polydata(input2_filename);

  compute_difference (input1, input2, diff_filename);

  return 0;
}
```

The first function is working fine. However, the output file from the second function is empty when I open it with paraview. for more information I am using VTK 8.2.0.

### Question

- Am I using vtkBooleanOperationPolyDataFilter correctly?
- Is it possible to use boolean operations directly on STL meshes?

I appreciate any suggestion to improve the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, you're using `vtkBooleanOperationPolyDataFilter` correctly.
2. `vtkSTLReader` creates a `vtkPolyData`, which is the correct input container for the boolean operation filter. Therefore: Yes, it is possible to read STLs and immediately process them with `vtkBooleanOperationPolyDataFilter`.

You lose some of the information when converting the output from `vtkPolyData` to `vtkUnstructuredGrid`. I think the shallow copy only copies the points, but not the cells. Have you checked the following?

```
std::cout << unstructured_grid->GetNumberOfCells() << std::endl;
std::cout << unstructured_grid->GetNumberOfPoints() << std::endl;
```

Since the output of the `vtkBooleanOperationPolyDataFilter` is a `vtkPolyData`, it doesn't make much sense to convert it to an unstructured grid anyway.

`vtkUnstructuredGrid` is often used to represent volumetric meshes, which you don't have. `vtkPolyData` is the standard container to represent surface meshes.

---

Regarding style, I'd rather operate with the already existing smart pointer for the reader instead of creating a new one for the poly data.

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkSTLReader> read_stl (std::string input) {
    auto stl_reader = vtkSmartPointer<vtkSTLReader>::New();
    stl_reader->SetFileName (input.c_str());
    stl_reader->Update();
    return stl_reader;
}
```

And then, to forward the data to the boolean filter:

```
auto boolean_operation = vtkSmartPointer<vtkBooleanOperationPolyDataFilter>::New();
boolean_operation->SetInputConnection (0, input1->GetOutputPort());
boolean_operation->SetInputConnection (1, input2->GetOutputPort());
boolean_operation->SetOperationToDifference();
boolean_operation->Update();
```

Just a suggestion. In case you don't know that resource yet, find [here](https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/Cxx/) a large number examples.

Answer (score 0):

About your questions

- I'm not sure why you're passing the `boolean_operation->GetOutput()` to an unstructured grid and not to a `vtkPolyData`
- in vtk you always work with polygonal data which is represented by a `vtkPolyData` object.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did this because at the end I want to store the result of difference operation as an unstructured grid. Do you suggest a different way?

Comment: I think you should store it as a vtkPolyData instead (as the name of the filter indicates..), at least I know for sure that in that case it works :)

Comment: @mmusy It isn't true that in vtk one uses just `vtkPolyData`. The best choice for a data container depends on the type of problem. `vtkPolyData` certainly is a good choice when working with surface meshes, but one'd prefer `vtkUnstructuredGrid` for volumetric meshes. vtk supports other structures as well: graphs, images, point clouds, grids, ...